# Identical space around \[ \] and the amsmath environments set to a personnal value

Tags: spacing, equations

I wish to have the same spaces around the brackets `\[` ... `\]` as the space around the environments `align` and `equation` (above and below, short or not) from `amsmath`, ideally (I set `\parskip=1ex`),

```
0.75\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25 \parskip
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\parskip{1ex}
\begin{document}



Some very very very very very long text
\begin{align*}
E \colon Q  &\longrightarrow QQ \\
(x_1 , x_2) &\longmapsto LL
\end{align*}
Some very very very very very long text.

Some very very very very very long text
\[ A=A \]
Some very very very very very long text.

Some very very very very very long text
\begin{equation*}
E \colon Q   =  QQ
\end{equation*}
Some very very very very very long text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the purpose of the modification.

Comment: Are you really really sure you want to redefine trivlist? If you answer yes to the previous question, ask your self if you are really really really sure that you want to redefine trivlist? You are redefining center, flushleft, tabbing, flushright, verbatim, all user defined theorem environments, and by default you are _not_ redefining `\[` which does not use trivlist in its default definition.

Comment: I do not want to but the `\[` is uses trivlist, I am fine with a new trivlist and in changing only the brackets. The definition is on section 55.2 of the source.

Comment: Probably showing an example of what you want to fix is better than showing complicated code.

Comment: The default \[ definition does not use a list, amsmath redefines \[ to be more similar to its alignment environments, so you probably need to give _complete_ example document showing a formula that you think gets bad spacing.

Comment: @egreg, I changed the question :)

Comment: `\parskip` is usually zero, do you mean `\baselineskip`? Or *what* do you mean?

Comment: @Manuel: \begin{align} \end{align} is longer to write than \\[ \\]. Plus I wish to agree on the spacing, not to be identical in their content. It is better to keep amsmath out of the ordinary tex commands.

Comment: My parskip is 1ex in general :)

Comment: Clearly your document setup is more complicated than what's shown in the code snippets you've posted. (Otherwise, how would `\parskip` be non-zero?) Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example) with the code you actually use.

Comment: @MIco: I added `\setlength\parskip{1ex}`, the space between the displays is 0.54cm, the 1ex in standard font is 4.30554pt so 0.15188988333334cm so there is about 3.5 \parskips around the formulas. This is my setup, there is nothing more really.

Comment: @Moustafa I get exactly the same spacing around `align` and around `equation*`; note that `amsmath` redefines `\[...\]` to be the same as `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`. So it's not at all clear what the question is about.

Comment: @egreg to set the spaces around the aforementioned environment to something as 0.75\parskip plus 0.25\parskip minus 0.25 \parskip since I find the spaces a little too big.

Comment: @egreg even when I remove the amsmath package I have the same distance for \\[\\] and \begin{equation*}